# Remove script name from url on redirect

Tags: .htaccess, perl, mod-rewrite, mojolicious

I'm running a simple Mojolicious::Lite app in CGI mode (Apache web server) on shared hosting account. It works great, but I can't figure out one thing. I want user to get redirected to the homepage when the requested route does not exist. With the code below it does, but there is my script name in the browser's address bar, which I don't want.

My routes look like this:

```
get '/' => sub { ... } => 'index';

get '/about' => 'about';

any '*' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->redirect_to('/');
};
```

My `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# -- force https --
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
# -----------------

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ script.pl/$1 [L,PT]
```

For example (type in browser -> end up in browser's address bar):

```
https://example.com/           https://example.com/
https://example.com/about      https://example.com/about
https://example.com/missing    https://example.com/script.pl (while home page is displayed as expected)
```

I just want it to show `https://example.com/` in the third case.

Why does this happen? I feel like `any '*'` route is either needs to do something else, or I need more rewrite rules, which I wasn't able to figure out yet.

I did try to add `ErrorDocument 404 https://example.ru/` in the .htaccess (tried both beginning and the end).

I also tried following before `RewriteBase /`, but it did not do anything.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  "^/$"
RewriteRule . script.pl [L]
```

Edit: just tried https://example.com/test on mobile browser, and saw how it got redirected to https://example.com/script.pl/test , and then automatically to https://example.com/script.pl

Comment: did you try `$self->redirect_to('https://example.com/');`

Comment: Delete you Browser cache also because a Browser do remember some redirects and do not go to the Server again.

Comment: Tried clearing cache. Did not try redirect with complete address, but would hate hardcoding domain in the script. I also test it locally via morbo, this will break this redirect. I will try it when I get to PC though to get more info. Thnx.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the browser or mod_rewrite.  I think M::L knows it's being run in CGI mode, and it knows the CGI script is `/script.pl`, so when you ask to redirect to the root of the M::L site (`/`), it knows it's reachable as `/script.pl/` (or just `/script.pl`). Maybe there's a way to configure it to do otherwise?

Comment: One solution is to use mod_proxy as a "reverse proxy". Use `ProxyPass` to redirect to your M::L site, and use `ProxyPassReverse` to fix the redirect locations.

Comment: Re "*I did try to add `ErrorDocument 404 https://example.ru/`*", Useless, because you don't return a 404.

Comment: Your question appears to be answered by [this page](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/wiki/Apache-deployment), which covers a number of solutions.

Comment: @ikegami you are right. when I added `before_dispatch` hook it worked. I guess I need to figure out how to get domain name from the info vailable via Mojolicious, so I don't have to hardcode it in.

Comment: You don't need just the domain, you need to know the entire base uri your rules redirect from. That's not available anywhere but in your rules.

Comment: The entire translated url is available in CGI vars, so you could rebuild the original url by hardcoding the rules to reverse the translation

Comment: The reverse proxy is the only truly transparent solution

Comment: looks like I can build it from `$c->req->url`, I'll try later. I'm not sure I can configure reverse proxy on shared hosting account

Comment: Unrelated to the problem at hand, but how is your experience with speed for the application? Can you feel that it's CGI as a user?

Comment: @simbabque this app is very small, and it loads as fast (as slow) as homepage of WordPress site I run on the same account (same server). I don't really have non-CGI Mojolicious app running out there to compare to. pingdom.com says it's faster than 59% of tested sites (tested from San Jose), but it's probably not a serious indicator to go by :-)

Comment: @ikegami @Webdesigner whoa, I tried running it locally via morbo, with this `before_dispatch` hook hack unmodified (with hardcoded url) -- and it still works on localhost, does not try to redirect to the hardcoded URL. magic! but it's great, I can leave it there and still validate app locally.